# The Completion of a Measure Space.

Tags: measure-theory, complete-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $$\mathcal{N} = \{N\subset X: \exists A\in \mathcal{T}\ \textrm{such that}\ N\subset A\wedge \mu(A)=0\}.$$
Let's define $$\mathcal{T}_1 = \{B\cup N: B\in \mathcal{T}\wedge N\in\mathcal{N}\}.$$
Prove that $\mathcal{T}_1=\dot{\mathcal{T}}=\sigma(\mathcal{T}\cup \mathcal{N})$.

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: @saad such a bully, close all my questions!!  shame on you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Prove that $\mathcal T_1$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. [This is the crucial part.]
2. Obviously, $\mathcal N\cup\mathcal T\subseteq\mathcal T_1$.
3. Whenever $\mathcal N\cup\mathcal T\subseteq\mathcal A$ for a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$, we have $\mathcal T_1\subseteq\mathcal A$.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I'll be forever grateful!